# Changing TStrings.Delimiter breaks search by name

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

The following code works:

```
var
  SL: TStrings;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.Add(Format('%s=%s', ['Alex', '14.05.1984']));

    ShowMessage(SL.Values['Alex']);
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

While this code does not work (cannot get value from name):

```
var
  SL: TStrings;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.Delimiter       := '|';  // <=== changed from default '=' char
    SL.QuoteChar       := '"';  // <=== added
    SL.StrictDelimiter := True; // <=== added

    SL.Add(Format('%s=%s', ['Alex', '14.05.1984']));

    ShowMessage(SL.Values['Alex']); // <=== returns an empty string
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Can someone help me?

**Edited**

```
program Sample;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Dialogs;

var
  SL: TStrings;
begin
  try
    SL := TStringList.Create;
    try
      SL.Delimiter := '|';
      SL.QuoteChar := '"';
      SL.StrictDelimiter := True;

  //    SL.Add(Format('%s=%s', ['Alex', '14.05.1984']));
      SL.LoadFromFile('ReplacementPairs.txt');
      ShowMessage(SL.Values['Alex']);
    finally
      SL.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

The content of the ReplacementPairs.txt file is:

```
Alex|14.05.1984
Paul|10.07.2015
Edith|18.11.1961
```

Comment: Why don't you use a dictionary?

Comment: so changing the delimiter breaks the search by name, even if the TStrings instance internally *knows* of the new delimiter.

Comment: Instead of adding the name-value pair yourself, why didn't you write: `SL.Values['Alex'] := '14.05.1984'`?

Comment: I really do wonder about what you say. Because in Delphi 6, `StrictDelimiter` doesn't exist, but when I remove that, the code does not return an empty string. And in XE3, I cannot manage to reproduce what you report.

Comment: you are right +David: I'll switch to a TDictionary: I was just curious if it is a bug of Delphi XE3

Comment: Your code does not produce the behaviour that you report. I suggest that you try running it. If only you'd produced a complete program, in a console app, you could just copy/paste a program that demonstrated the behaviour. As it stands, the question makes no sense because the behaviour you report cannot be reproduced.

Comment: This is yet again a perfect example of one you must always provide an MCVE. I hope that you take that on board.

Comment: Re-edited the sample code adding a sample project: the problems (IMO) seems to came when I populate the TStringList with LoadFromFile, (which  Is what I was doing in my code without telling you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property that determines the separator between names and values is [`NameValueSeparator`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.NameValueSeparator). So, set that to `'|'` and the code should behave as you desire.

I cannot help but feel that a dictionary would be more suitable to your needs.

Comment: By the time I was writing an apologizing message for you and the other people, you anticipated me: anyway: THANK YOU!

Comment: You made a mistake in your original question. That can happen. But you did a good job of fixing it when it came under fire! Well done. I reversed my voting because of that. However, I cannot stress enough the importance of providing an MCVE. A short 20 line console app would have done the job. It really makes the questions better for everyone.

Comment: Yes @David: you are right! Lesson learned for future questions :-)